# Rotar un div durante 30 segundos Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Saludos, mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo un bloque div el cual necesito que se mantenga girando durante X cantidad de segundos, he probado con algunas librerias Jquery pero no he podido lograr controlar el tiempo en que este se mantiene girando y la velocidad, esto es importante. Saludos.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item{
    height: 20rem;
    width: 20rem;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="item" class="item"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/40855/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el código que tengas así podemos ayudarte a identificar el problema.

Comment: Listo, mi problema es que necesito hacer que el div central gire durante 45 segundos, a 30 rpm. Saludos.

Comment: Estaría faltando que también incluyas el contenido de `script.js`

Comment: Es cada 45 segundos? O solo por 45 segundos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer: `sec = 60 / rpm` para saber la duración de un giro, sabiendo ésto lo puedes animar vía `@keyframes`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#go');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const rpm = document.querySelector('#rpm');
const timeout = document.querySelector('#timeout');
let tid = null; // timeout id

go.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sec = 60 / parseInt(rpm.value);
  const millisec = parseInt(timeout.value) * 1000;
  rotate.stop();
  rotate.start(sec, millisec);
});

const rotate = {
  stop() {
   if (tid) {
    window.clearTimeout(tid);
    }
   box.removeAttribute('style');
    box.classList.remove('animated');
  },
  start (sec, millisec) {
   box.style.animationDuration = `${sec}s`;
    box.classList.add('animated');
    tid = window.setTimeout(() => {
      box.classList.remove('animated');
    }, millisec);
  }
}

//rotate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.form {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.form input {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}
.form input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 188, 255, .7);
  outline: none;
}
.form button {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
.  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.form button:active {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
.form button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.draw {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex:  1;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
.box.animated {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<section class="form">
  <input type="number" id="rpm" placeholder="Ingresa las RPM" required>
  <input type="number" id="timeout" placeholder="Ingrese tiempo límite (seg)" required>
  <button id="go">Aplicar</button>
</section>
<section class="draw">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Me encanto tu respuesta, muchas gracias. Una última consulta, hay alguna manera en que yo pueda detectar que el div se encuentra por ejemplo a 30°? o a 45°? Por ejemplo que cada vez que el div se encuentre entre 20 y 25° mande un console log (por ejemplo)

Comment: Genial respuesta! Debe ser la aceptada! Haciendo pruebas con el código de mi respuesta, veo que hay problemas con el setInterval ya que no aceptada cantidades de tiempo menores a 50 ms, tu código funciona en cualquier caso.

Comment: Claro que se puede, solo debes hacer cálculos matemáticos. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer una especie de "breakpoints" para que te informe cuándo llegó a tantos grados. Para esto en el momento en el cual empiezas la rotación debes empezar otra función la cual iterará cada x milisegundos, dentro de ella debes calcular en qué grado se encuentra teniendo en cuenta el tiempo actual de recorrido, el tiempo que toma el giro y la cantidad de grados (360). Si te gusta la trigonometría lo hallarás divertido ;)

Comment: Seguro José, es un código sin ningún tipo de validaciones ;)

Comment: guzgarcia, no he logrado entender bien lo que me aconsejas, podrías darme un ejemplo? gracias

Comment: Claro. Lo que necesitarás es usar [raf](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), no es necesario, pero es lo más óptimo. Cuando inicias la rotación, en ese instante debes empezar el loop con raf de modo que inicien el mismo instante. El loop raf iterará cada milisegundo aproximadamente, por lo que si los RPM que exiges no son demasiados, es posible capturar el momento cuando el giro "llegue a X grados".

Comment: Digamos que se está animando a 30 RPM, entonces, la velocidad de giro será de `2 segundos`. Entonces, si 2 segundos son necesarios para un giro de 360°, ¿cuántos milisegundos equivale a 1°? Matemática básica. Entonces, si `5.55` ms equivale a 1°, cuando se esté por el milisegundo `222` se está llegando a `40°`. Obviamente lo que necesitas es una variable fuera del loop que vaya sumando los milisegundos transcurridos, para, una vez llegados a `222` o a cualquier otro, lo puedas detectar. No es una ciencia exacta, en una iteración puedes llevar `207ms` y en la otra `229`, debes tener en cuenta.

Comment: me gustaria que me ayudaras, quisiera hacer girar un elemento de una pagina web, como el ejemplo que muestas aqui, pero no logro que funcione

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo sin utilzar ninguna librertía adicional. Hacemos uso de las funciones `setTimeout` y `setInterval`, además de aplicarle el CSS mediante JS `transform : rotate(angulo deg)`

```js
var TIEMPO_1_GRADO = 10 // 10 ms
var TIEMPO_TOTAL   = 5 * 1000 // 5 segundos
var anguloActual  = 0
var divGirar       = document.getElementById('div-girar')
function girar(){
  if(anguloActual == 360) anguloActual = 0
  divGirar.style.transform = 'rotate(' + anguloActual + 'deg)'
  anguloActual++
}

var intervalID = setInterval(girar, TIEMPO_1_GRADO)

setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(intervalID)
}, TIEMPO_TOTAL)
```

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item{
    height: 20rem;
    width: 20rem;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-girar" class="item"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando [`$.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$("#start").click(function() {
  $("#item").animate({
    left: 90
  }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');  
    },
    duration: 3000
  });
});
```

```css
.item{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item" class="item"></div>

<button id="start">Animar!</button>
```

**Explicación:**

En este caso utilizo la propiedad `left` (podría usar cualquier otra) la cual no afectara de ninguna forma la ubicación del mismo (ya que el elemento no esta posicionado de forma absoluta). El truco se basa en modificar una propiedad que no afecte realmente el elemento, pero en cada paso (`step`) de la animación rotar gradualmente el elemento utilizando  `transform','rotate([GRADOS]deg)`.